# What is the difference between `$this->name` and `$this->$name`?

Tags: php, class

I am wondering what is the difference between `$this->name` and `$this->$name`? Also does `$this` have to be strictly named *this* or can it be anything?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`$this` is a reserved variable name and can not be used for anything else. It specifically points you to the object your are currently working in. You have to use `$this` because you do not know what variable object will be assigned to.

`$this->name` refers to the current class's variable `name`

`$this->$name` refers to the class variable of whatever the value of `$name` is. Thus

```
$name = "name";
echo $this->$name; // echos the value of $this->name.

$name = "test";
echo $this->$name;  // echos the value of $this->test
```

Answer (score 6):

$this is a reserved name used in PHP to point to the current instance of the class you are using it in *([quoting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php))* :

> The pseudo-variable `$this` is available
>   when a method is called from within an
>   object context. 
> `$this` is a reference
>   to the calling object (usually the
>   object to which the method belongs,
>   but possibly another object, if the
>   method is called statically from the
>   context of a secondary object).

When using `$this->name`, you are accessing the property with the name `name` of the current object.

When using `$this->$name`, $name is determined before accessing the property -- which means you'll access the property which name is contained in the `$name` local variable.

For instance, with this portion of code :

```
$name = 'abc';
echo $this->$name;
```

You'll actually echo the content of the abc property, as if you had written :

```
echo $this->abc;
```

When doing this, you are using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) *(quoting)* :

> Class properties may also be accessed
>   using variable property names. 
> The
>   variable property name will be
>   resolved within the scope from which
>   the call is made. 
> For instance, if you
>   have an expression such as `$foo->$bar`,
>   then the local scope will be examined
>   for `$bar` and its value will be used as
>   the name of the property of `$foo`. 
> This
>   is also true if $bar is an array
>   access.

Comment: You have an error in your syntax. Mixing single quotes with double quotes are we? (Tried to fix it, and you overwrote me)

Comment: @Chacha : ergh, once again, too early in the morning ^^ thanks for noticing that :-) -- huhu, we both edited my answer to correct that problem, I see :-D ;; and we edited our comments at the same time, too :-D

Comment: If we were programming, we'd be sunk  as StackOverflow doesn't have comment checkouts/locks :)

Comment: If we were programming, we would either use transactions, or have some conflicts when trying to commit our modifications ^^ *(well, at least for the answer's edition)*

Comment: I think someone has suggested that to Jeff. Maybe he'll listen to it after hes stopped telling himself how good the sliding comment timer is...

Comment: It's not **that bad** either : I don't quite that often edit at the same time another user does -- and for comments, it's not a catastrophy either (and being able to edit comments helps fixing the situations in which cross-posting happens)

Answer (score 2):

This question just popped up after an update. I liked the question, so I thought I'd add my own example of the difference.

```
class Test
{
    public $bar = 'bar';
    public $foo = 'foo';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $bar = 'foo';

        $this->bar; // bar
        $this->$bar; // foo
    }
}
```